# How to reinstall a managed beta package without losing custom objects data?

Tags: data-export, import, beta-managed-package, data-import

I created a managed package that, among other things, defines a custom object.
I installed this package on my client's Sandbox and created several instances of this custom object.

Now I've created a new version of this (beta) package.
When I try to re-install it, Salesforce tells me that I need to delete the previous version of the package from the Sandbox first.
[image]

Is there a way to either:

- Reinstall the beta package without deleting the previous version?
- Or export the custom object instances I created, uninstall the package, install the package and then import them back?

My main goal is to keep the custom objects I defined, so I don't have to manually create them again.

Answer (score 3):

For your point first thats not possible. You need to first uninstall that package first.

For second point you can take a offline backup in Eclipse and then remove dependency of your Beta package and then reinstall again. And in end from backup create the fields and update the components.

But every time you try to install the package you need to run this exercise. For the data SF provide option to take backup which you can use.